# Ansible - Create AD Group with ManagedBy allowed to edit membership

Tags: active-directory, ansible

I can create easly group in Ansible using *win_domain_group_module*. But I need to create it with this option :
[image]

I've got no problems to set the ManagedBy option defining the user that needs to be able to manage Group's membership but I don't know how to enable this option.

I've read group's attributes in powershell but it doesn't seems to contains this option :

```
CanonicalName, CN, Created, createTimeStamp, Deleted, Description, DisplayName, DistinguishedName, dSCorePropagationData, GroupCategory, GroupScope, groupType, HomePage, instanceType, isDeleted, LastKnownParent, ManagedBy, member, MemberOf, Members, Modified, modifyTimeStamp, Name, nTSecurityDescriptor, ObjectCategory, ObjectClass, ObjectGUID, objectSid, ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion, SamAccountName, sAMAccountType, sDRightsEffective, SID, SIDHistory, uSNChanged, uSNCreated, whenChanged, whenCreated
```

With or without the option enable all attributes excepted dates are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it.
I think the problem is that this option is a security mask and not an AD group's option.

With better research I managed to put this powershell script :

```
param(
        [string]$groupname=""
)

Import-Module ActiveDirectory


if($groupname -eq ""){
        Write-Host('Error. Missing $groupname parameter.')
}

$guid=[guid]'THIS GUID HAS TO BE FOUND ON YOUR AD'
$user = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount("Domain\GroupManagerAccount")
$sid=$user.translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier])
$ad_path_string="ad:\cn=" + $groupname + ",ou=MyOU,dc=Domain,dc=com"
$acl = Get-Acl -Path $ad_path_string
$ctrl = [System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType]::Allow
$rights = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryRights]::WriteProperty -bor[System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryRights]::ExtendedRight
$intype = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectorySecurityInheritance]::None

$rule = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryAccessRule($sid,$rights,$ctrl,$guid)
$acl.AddAccessRule($rule)
Set-Acl -acl $acl -path $ad_path_string
```

To check your right GUID you can do this :

1. Connect on your AD
2. Open ADSI Edit
3. Right-Click ADSI Edit and select Connect To
4. Select a well known Naming Context -> Configuration -> Ok
5. Select CN=Configuration and then CN=Extended-Rights
6. Open CN=Self-Membership
7. Find the guid under rightsGuid

I putted it on my AWX server. Then in my .yml that create groups using `win_domain_group` module I added 2 tasks for my Active Directory server :

```
  - name: Transfering the AD rights management script to the hosts
    win_copy:
      src: MyScript.ps1
      dest: C:\temp\

  - name: Adding the account right to edit membership on the new group in AD
    win_shell: C:\temp\MyScript.ps1 -groupname MyNewGroup
    become: yes
    become_user: Administrateur
```

Be aware that my server was installed with the french language. If you're using english the `become_user` should be `Administrator`. All credit goes to shirl9141 who wrote [this post](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/blur-lines_-powershell_-author_shirleym/2013/10/07/manager-can-update-membership-list-part-1/).